# Silent install of Japanese Language Pack in Win7

Tags: windows-7, automation, language

Every year, due to re-imaging, I am forced to find a way to install the Japanese language pack on a collection of 30 computers. Each year I look for a way to automate this process, and each year I am forced to do this manually. Maybe this year will be different. Has anyone had any luck with installing and configuring far east language support for windows 7 without user interaction?

I have already downloaded kb972813 and have a way to get it out to the computers. What I normally do is this:

1. Run the EXE, use the default settings.
2. Open up language settings and create the JP keyboard.
3. Configure the language bar settings.
4. Copy settings to default user.
5. Delete the local user cache.
6. Sign the different user accounts in to make sure that the default settings are correct.

This whole process takes about 10 minutes, multiply that out by 30 machines and you are looking at a 5 hour process. If I can log into all of the computers at once, I can normally cut that down to about an hour.

Any ideas would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: Why can't you have this preinstalled on your (presumably resealed with sysprep) image?

Comment: This is only used by a few users about a half dozen times a year. We have more than the 30 computers in this lab that would never use Japanese. The imaging manager would not add this to the image when so few users need it.

Comment: Couldn't you possibly clone one computer to the thirty, or put the executable with a batch file or something with the preconfigured settings? (that's just a suggestion.. I am not sure if a batch file can do that, but something probably can)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is actually a comand line utility to do this called lpksetup.exe

Source: 
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc748922%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

To install a language pack you must do the following:

1. Download the language pack kb executable for your language.
2. Extract the cab file out of it.
3. Use lpksetup to install the cab file.
4. Use regedit to import your keyboard and language bar settings.
5. Delete all the local user profiles so the configurations for new users will be up to date.

It's actually an easy process, but it takes a registry snapshot comparison to get all the registry settings figured out. The process isn't perfect and will take a bit of work to make it 100% silent but it works.